# Erro ao conectar no Banco de Dados - Firebird/Java

Tags: java, firebird

Estou tentando conectar uma aplicação desktop java em um banco de dados Firebird e no console do eclipse mostra o seguinte erro: "PM org.firebirdsql.logging.JulLogger warn: WARNING: No connection character set specified (property lc_ctype, encoding, charSet or localEncoding), defaulting to character set NONE".

Estou utilizando o jaybird 4 para o java 8 e o jdbc 4.2.

Abaixo o método da minha conexão:

```
protected boolean conectaLD()
{
    {

    String driverName = "org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBDriver";
    Class.forName(driverName);

    String databaseURL = "jdbc:firebirdsql:192.168.0.32:c:/bdteste/dosimetria.fdb";

    con_LD = DriverManager.getConnection(databaseURL,"claudio","alparole");

    con_LD.setAutoCommit(false);

    stmt_LD = con_LD.createStatement();
    stmt_LD2 = con_LD.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);

    }
    catch(java.lang.Exception ex)
    {
        con_LD = null;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,""+ex.getMessage(),"1 - Falha ao criar uma Connection :",0);
        return false;
    }
    return true;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Para evitar erros como esse é necessário saber a versão do Firebird e do Java instalado. No meu projeto estou usando o Firebird 2.5 e o Java 8. O erro ocorreu pois a versão do drive JDBC era incompatível com a versão do Firebird. Verifiquei a versão do Firebird e constatei que é a 2.5, então resolvi o erro baixando o jaybird 2.2.15 para Java 8 e adicionando o jar ao meu projeto.

Se você tiver mais duvidas sobre isso, consulte a documentação na seção 9.8: https://firebirdsql.github.io/jaybird-manual/jaybird_manual.html?fbclid=IwAR2Pr2Mphn0lrDFKl2NggpcHqn_THsCEXLIqyLl_h_s-zcKCVjEujXkNDA0#_available_encodings